# Возникает ошибка при создании листов типа DataTable

Tags: c#

```
  private DataTable TablePoint()
    {
        //создаём таблицу
        DataTable dtPoint = new DataTable();
        //создаём три колонки
        DataColumn x = new DataColumn("x", typeof(Double));
        DataColumn y = new DataColumn("y", typeof(Double));
        //добавляем колонки в таблицу
        dtPoint.Columns.Add(x);
        dtPoint.Columns.Add(y);

        return dtPoint;
    }

    List<DataTable> listDt = new List<DataTable>();
    listDt = null;
    listDt.Add(TablePoint());// ошибка
    DataRow newRowListDt = null;
   foreach (XElement elm in xDoc.Descendants("point"))
            {
                newRowListDt = listDt[0].NewRow();

                if (elm.Element("x") != null)
                {
                    newRowListDt["x"] = double.Parse(elm.Element("x").Value);
                }

                if (elm.Element("y") != null)
                {
                    newRowListDt["y"] = double.Parse(elm.Element("y").Value);
                }
                listDt[0].Rows.Add(newRowListDt);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Строчкой

```
listDt = null;
```

вы уничтожаете созданный в предыдущей строке список, просто удалите её.

Comment: Вы были правы.....